# Drawing parallel lines using Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For the below code how I can make parallel lines with a specified distance.
given first line points A(0,7)   B(5,2)
Second line(3,2)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

x=[0, 7]
y=[5, 2]
plt.plot(x,y)

o = np.subtract(2, 7)
q = np.subtract(5, 0)
slope = o/q

#(m,p) are the new coordinates to plot the parallel line
m = 3
p = 2

axes = plt.gca()
x_val = np.array(axes.get_xlim())
y_val = np.array(slope*(x_val - m) + p)
plt.plot(x_val,y_val, color="black", linestyle="--")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, any particular reason you're doing `o = np.subtract(2,7)` instead of `o = 2 - 7`?

Comment: Yes, I want to modify it later with variables.

Comment: Ok, but ordinary subtraction can _also_ involve variables.

Comment: ok i will edit that.

Comment: If the lines are parallel, we know that the slope is constant. What is m and p in terms of x and y? Are you familiar with the concept of intercept?

Answer (score 2):

To get the slope of your line you need to calculate `(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`. You are doing `(y2 - x2) / (y1 - x1)`. So you just need to calculate the correct slope by

```
o = np.subtract(2, 5)  # y[1] - y[0]
q = np.subtract(7, 0)  # x[1] - x[0]
slope = o/q
```

which will give a slope of approx. -0.42857. This will give you the following plot:

[image: Plot of the two lines]